# ${\rm Hom}_R(eR,eR)\cong eRe$ when $e$ is idempotent in ring $R$

Tags: ring-theory

> **Theorem:** Let $R$ be (not necessarily commutative) ring with unity and $e$ a non-zero idempotent. Then 
>   $${\rm Hom}_R(eR,eR)\cong eRe \,\,\,\, (\mbox{isomorphic as abelian groups}).$$

I gave argument for the proof:

(1) Any $f\in {\rm Hom}_R(eR,eR)$ is determined by $f(e)$ [This is simply because the right $R$-module appearing in the domain of $f$ is generated by single element $e$.]

(2) Next, since $e$ is idempotent, it is easy to see that $f(e)$ lies in $eRe$. So to each $f$, we associate an element in $eRe$.

So from these remarks, it is easy to obtain desired map for isomorphism in the Theorem, then one can show that the map is actually an isomorphism.

**Q.** Beside this symbolic argument, I didn't understand the statement of the theorem and intuition behind it. Can one explain what the upshot of the theorem is?

Comment: More generally, if $e_1,e_2$ are idempotents, then $\hom_R(e_1R,e_2R)\cong e_2Re_1$. If $e_1=e_2$, these are isomorphic as rings, as well. These rings $eRe$ appear in the Morita theory.

Comment: It may help you to check out what's going on, when $R=M_n(k)$ is the algebra of $n\times n$ matrices over a field $k$, and $e$ is a diagonal idempotent with all entries $1$ or $0$. Say, if $\ell<n$ first entries are $1$ and the rest $0$, then $eR$ is essentially the space of $\ell\times n$ matrices. The endomorphisms are gotten by *left* multiplication by an $\ell\times\ell$ matrix. Just as well, given that $eRe$ is essentially the algebra of $\ell\times\ell$-matrices.

Comment: @Jyrki: this is a good example.